# jQuery Mobile header button float left and right

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

i'm trying to get the header to have two sets of button on the left and right, but i'm having trouble getting everything to line up and float left/right properly. Any idea on an easy way to accomplish this.

```
     <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<!-- back button -->                    
       <a style=" margin:5px 0 10px 0;" data-role="button" 
    data-transition="slide" data-theme="b" href="#track_dash" 
    data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">
          Back
       </a>

<!-- chart switch -->                    
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float: right;">
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                       <input name="radiobuttons5" id="radio7" value="radio1" type="radio" />
                       <label for="radio7">
                            List
                       </label>
                       <input name="radiobuttons5" id="radio8" value="radio8" type="radio" />
                       <label for="radio8">
                            Chart
                       </label>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>

      </div>
```

[image: left side design / right side actual coded design]

Answer (score 16):

Use `class="ui-btn-left` on the back button and `class="ui-btn-right"` on the controlgroup.

Maybe you also need to put a header between both elements, at least empty `<h1></h1>`

Answer (score 7):

you probably figured out a solution by now but I did this in my footer and it worked out for me:

```
<div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed" data-id="myFooter">
    <div class="footerContainer">    
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"class="ui-btn-left">Cancel</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially I wrapped my buttons in a div and that allowed me to use ui-btn-left and right to float the buttons and align them properly doesn't seem to cause any conflicts so far.

Here's the css

```
.footerContainer{
    width:97%;
    height:38px;
    border:none;
    position:relative;
    }
```

I set the width to 97% because 100% will take the width plus padding and position:relative so that the float is contained.